# Linear Algebra - Find the line that passes through a point and intersects two lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically I have to find a line that passes through a point and intersects two lines.

The Point $P=(6,-2,-2)$

The first Line is

$$x = 1+t$$
$$y = 5 + 2t$$
$$z = 3 +4t$$

The second line is

$$x = 3 + 3s $$
$$y = 1 + s $$
$$z = 4 + 2s $$

I have to express the answer in parametric form:

$$x = 6 + Aw $$
$$y = -2 + Bw $$
$$z = -2 + Cw $$

I basically have to find $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how to start it, I'm clueless at this point, the teacher gave us a suggestion, like find the perpendicular from first line to the third line and the second line to the third line and [A,B,C] would equal the perpendicular from first line to third and second line to third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane containing all lines through $P$ and some point on the first line has normal vector
$$
\vec n_{\alpha}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1-6\\
5-(-2)\\
3-(-2)
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
When this cross product has been computed, a similar computation can be carried out to determine a normal vector $\vec n_{\beta}$ for the plane containing the point and the second line. Then a direction vector for the line of intersection can be found as
$$
\vec r=\vec n_{\alpha}\times\vec n_{\beta}
$$
and the coordinates of $\vec r$ should contain the figures $A,B,C$ that you seek.

---

I did just that and ended up with $\vec r=\langle 1,2,4\rangle^T$ after having reduced the size of the vector. If this is correct, the problem has no solutions since then the line through $P$ never intersects the first line, as it is parallel to it.

Comment: in the first bracket, you are subtracting from Point P from the first line and then doing the cross product of that to (1,2,4)?

Comment: @ShawnEdward: Yes. Let $Q=(1,5,3)$ denote immediately known point on the first line. Then $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\langle 1,2,4\rangle$ are vectors in the first mentioned plane, so their cross product becomes a normal vector for that plane.

Comment: When you finding  PQ isn't it  Q - P, so like in the first bracket, wouldn't it be 1-6, 5- (-2) and so on..?

Comment: @ShawnEdward: Yes, you are right about that :o) Note that $\overrightarrow{QP}$ works equally well.

Comment: for some reason I didn't get the answer you got

Comment: @ShawnEdward: I do not know how I got the wrong answer the first time. Now I have it as $\vec r=\langle 1,2,4\rangle^T$ which basically tells me that the problem has no solution. I even made a plot in GeoGebra of the situation which confirmed this.

Comment: yeah I got that too, thanks for ur help!

Comment: The line intersecting the two planes is parallel to the first line. In theory this procedure should work though.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** define a plane containing the point and first line, the same for 2nd line